Next.js middleware not allowing "/" route
I'm currently working on creating a middleware for a Next.js 14 application. I'm trying to configure the middleware to allow the "/" route, but despite several attempts, I'm still encountering issues where the middleware doesn't seem to recognize the "/" route.
Here's my current middleware configuration:
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};

I've tried various modifications to the regular expression pattern to explicitly allow the "/" route, but none seem to work. I've also attempted alternative configurations, such as using the exclude property, but with no success.
Can someone please provide guidance on how to properly configure the middleware to allow the "/" route? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
Next.js version: 14
Middleware library: next-auth/middleware
Any error messages encountered: No error messages, but the "/" route is not being allowed as expected.

"/((?!api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|/$).*)",

try this once hope it works


Please add some sample api example... it should work

When you run this regex /((?!api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*) over / it will match as protected route because ?! makes the group api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico optional.

To execlude / from protect routes you can make the group required by removing ?! part
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};


Notice how the group in the first diagram is "negative lookahead" and the second is not

with matcher: ["/((api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"], i'm getting `Error parsing /((api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-route-source
Reason: Capturing groups are not allowed at 2
/((api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)
^
source parse failed for route {"source":"/((api|login|register|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"}
Error: Invalid middleware found`
